CupertinoSliverRefreshControl not working with SliverList inside a CustomScrollView
I'm trying to a achieve to build a Scrollable list of appointments, where a header is pinned on top of the list until the end of its content is reached and then it swaps with the next one.
It should trigger the pull to refresh system as usual when pulling down from the first item of the first list.
I first made a PullToRefreshWidget that works both on Android using the RefreshIndicator directly, and on iOS using a CustomScrollView with CupertinoSliverRefreshControl as first Sliver.
I then made an OuterList widget that is a CustomScrollView with inside a list of InnerList.
InnerList is a SliverList with a Header that pins on top as we scroll through the list of time slots.
So in a Column I have them set like so:
...

Expanded(
              child: PullToRefreshWidget(
                  child: const  OuterList(),
                  onRefresh: () {
                    return Future(() => print('onRefresh'));
                  }),
            ),

The problem is that when I pull down from the InnerList the PullToRefreshWidget doesn't sense it and doesn't trigger the onRefresh callback.
I first tried with nested ListView.builder but I couldn't achieve the pinned header requirement, but the pull to refresh was working properly.
So I used https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools package to achieve it, but it brakes the pull to refresh.
Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?
Many thanks.
pull to refresh widget
class PullToRefreshWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Future Function() onRefresh;
  const PullToRefreshWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
    required this.onRefresh,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return materialApp()
        ? RefreshableWidgetAndroid(
            onRefresh: onRefresh,
            child: child,
          )
        : RefreshableWidgetIOS(
            onRefresh: onRefresh,
            child: child,
          );
  }
}

class RefreshableWidgetAndroid extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Future Function() onRefresh;
  const RefreshableWidgetAndroid(
      {super.key, required this.child, required this.onRefresh});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: onRefresh,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}

class RefreshableWidgetIOS extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Future Function() onRefresh;
  const RefreshableWidgetIOS({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
    required this.onRefresh,
    // required this.controller,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      // shrinkWrap: true,
      // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      // controller: controller,
      slivers: [
        CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(
          onRefresh: onRefresh,
        ),
        SliverFillRemaining(
          child: child,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

main list widget
class OuterList extends StatefulWidget {
  const OuterList({super.key});

  @override
  State<OuterList> createState() => _OuterListState();
}

class _OuterListState extends State<OuterList> {
  late final ScrollController _mainScrollController;
  Map<String, List<DateTime>> groupedDates = {};
  int? currentIndex = 0;
  double viewportDimension = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _generateAvailableTimes();

    _mainScrollController = ScrollController();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        viewportDimension = _mainScrollController.position.viewportDimension;
        print('viewportDimension is $viewportDimension');
      });
    });
  }

  void _generateAvailableTimes() {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    final startOfWeek = now.subtract(Duration(days: now.weekday - 1));
    final List<DateTime> dates = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      final day = startOfWeek.add(Duration(days: i));
      final isThursdayOrSaturday =
          day.weekday == DateTime.thursday || day.weekday == DateTime.saturday;
      final endHour = isThursdayOrSaturday ? 12 : 18;

      for (int hour = 8; hour <= endHour; hour++) {
        for (int minute = 0; minute < 60; minute += 30) {
          if (hour == 8 && minute < 30) continue;
          dates.add(DateTime(day.year, day.month, day.day, hour, minute));
        }
      }
    }

    groupedDates = dates.fold({}, (Map<String, List<DateTime>> map, date) {
      final dayStr = DateFormat('EEEE, dd MMMM').format(date);
      if (!map.containsKey(dayStr)) {
        map[dayStr] = [];
      }
      map[dayStr]!.add(date);
      return map;
    });

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final days = groupedDates.keys.toList();
    return Material(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 550,
        child: CustomScrollView(
          controller: _mainScrollController,
          // shrinkWrap:
          //     true, // Important for center content when it is smaller that screen height
          // physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(
          //     // parent: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          //     ),

          slivers: [
            for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i++) ...[
              ExpandableItem(
                  index: i,
                  day: days[i],
                  times: groupedDates[days[i]]!,
                  isExpanded: true,
                  onExpand: () {})
            ]
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

time slot list widget
class ExpandableItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  final String day;
  final List<DateTime> times;
  final bool isExpanded;
  final VoidCallback onExpand;

  const ExpandableItem(
      {super.key,
      required this.index,
      required this.day,
      required this.times,
      required this.isExpanded,
      required this.onExpand});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiSliver(pushPinnedChildren: true, children: [
      SliverPinnedHeader(
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.amber,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
              topRight: Radius.circular(5),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(5),
            ),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          // child: Center(
          child: Text(
            day,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          // ),
        ),
      ),
      SliverList.builder(
        itemCount: times.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final time = times[index];
          final timeStr = DateFormat('HH:mm').format(time);
          return SizedBox(
            height: 60,
            child: ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.access_time),
              title: Text(timeStr),
            ),
          );
        },
      )
    ]);
  }
}

class Section extends MultiSliver {
  Section({
    Key? key,
    required String title,
    Color headerColor = Colors.white,
    Color titleColor = Colors.black,
    required List<Widget> items,
  }) : super(
          key: key,
          pushPinnedChildren: true,
          children: [
            SliverPinnedHeader(
              child: ColoredBox(
                color: headerColor,
                child: ListTile(
                  textColor: titleColor,
                  title: Text(title),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate.fixed(items),
            )
          ],
        );
}

